# Return values from dialog

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous

I found some code like this for a simple vue y/n dialog

```
methods: {
    open () {
      this.dialog = true
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        this.resolve = resolve
      })
    },
    yes: function () {
      this.dialog = false
      this.resolve(true)
    },
    no: function () {
      this.dialog = false
      this.resolve(false)
    }
  }
```

And you open the dialog like this and get the response

```
this.$refs.CalibratorConfirmDialog.open().then(resp => {console.log(resp)})
```

After trying to implement it i got a few errors like

Cannot set property resolve of undefined in the open() function

And this.resolve(true) is not a function

The answer i got this from was voted up a bit so im wondering if theres something im doing wrong (the dialog opens i can click the buttons and close it just the returning an answer logic isnt working)

Answer (score 0):

Did you already declare the resolve variable in your data ? Like

```
data () {
   return {
     resolve:null
   }
}
```

And change your promise to arrow function,

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.resolve = resolve
})
```

Comment: i did have the variable.. this did stop the error tho but Im not getting the value